# Laravel: extending a layout in a child view from a package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

We have been converting our MVC contents into separate packages from our Laravel app. We still keep our layouts in the actual application, but the problem is that the **packages are not able to use the `@extends('layouts.mainlayout')` directive** approach to templating where we can render the sections inside the layout like such: `<title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>` using the section directives.

Here is a snapshot of the design of the app:

**Laravel Application**

*Main layout aka "master" page of the entire application*

```
 resources/views/layouts/mainlayout.blade.php
```

**Example of a view from the application using mainlayout.blade.php**

ex: resources/views/home/index.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.mainlayout')
 @section('title')
     Home 
 @stop

 @section('css') 
    @parent
   <style>
     .#alp{font-size: 12pt;}
   </style>
 @stop

@section('content')
<table id="alp" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
@stop

@section('custom_js')
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#alp').DataTable( {
                "responsive": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "initComplete": function(){
            CTSA.showRecordCount(t);
            CTSA.Flags.initCompleteDt = true;
        },
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            if(CTSA.Flags.initCompleteDt)
                CTSA.showRecordCount(t);
        }       
    });
} );
</script>
@stop
```

**NOT WORKING PROPERLY**

**Example from package using mainlayout.blade.php**

ex: packages/testpackage/resources/views/test.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.mainlayout.php')

 @section('title')
     Test Page 
 @stop
```

I can get the package to use the layout, but I cannot get it to use it the way it should be using it via `@extends('layouts.mainlayout')`. Currently it basically just crams the `test.blade.php` view into the `mainlayout.blade.php` layout.

It basically uses the mainlayout.blade.php template like this:

resources/views/layouts/mainlayout.blade.php

```
@section('content')
 Contents of view test.blade.php get crammed here
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your packages have access to the root directory of your laravel application by default!

When you create a package and publish a package in your Laravel Application/Project a fresh **copy of the package resides in `/vendor/package-name`**

The **ACTUAL published package** resides in your Laravel Application/Project in the normal locations just like if it was created from within the Application/Project!

For instance,

Your package's assets ie: css,js,images get published in the app's **public folder**

**Laravel/App infrastructure:**

```
App
   -Http
        -Controllers
                -AppController
                -PackageController 
   -Listeners
   -Console
public
   -assets
         -images
   -css
   -js
   -package-name
         -assets
                -images
         -css
         -js
resources
   -views
         -layouts
                -masterLayout.blade.php
                -partials
         -package-name
                -packageChildView.blade.php 
                -package-partials
```

As you can see, all of your packages can get to the layouts just fine `/resources/views/`! You can also get to `public/` by default.

When taking over a large/unstructured project make sure you do a search on the file in question because you may be in for a surprise to find out that there are multiple copies of a file and the file your working on and in question may be the wrong one!

So in short,

The package will have access to the layouts in the application. When you publish your views they will look in [two spots for the layouts/views by default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#views).

> Laravel actually registers two locations for your views: the
>   application's resources/views/vendor directory and the directory you
>   specify.

Answer (score 1):

when extend a layout, by default Laravel will use layout from Laravel project
`project/resources/views/layouts/sample_layout.blade.php`

```php
@extend('layouts.sample_layout')
```

If we want to use package layout, assume your package layout like this

```
package_name/resources/views/layouts/pk_layout.blade.php
```

we have to use this

```
@extend('package_name::layouts.pk_layout')
```